# How to use /param for multiple parameters for kitchen?

Tags: pentaho

Right now this is my command `kitchen.bat /file C:\GitSandbox\360Insight\Kettle\Source\UpdateMasterCustomerAttributeData(LocalDev).kjb /r
ep 360Insight /param FULL_REFRESH=1 TESTING=1` but I'm not sure if this is the proper way to be using the `/param` option. Do I need multiple `/param` options or will this work?

I am now sure that this is not working correctly. What is the correct way to pass multiple user parameters to a kettle job with kitchen?

Comment: Have you seen the Kitchen user documentation? Specifically: [Kitchen.bat options](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Kitchen+User+Documentation#KitchenUserDocumentation-Commandlineoptions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each instance of `/param` should take on the following form:

```
/param "variable_name:value"
```

Without the wrapping quotes, the value will not be set. This can be repeated for multiple variables.